# How can I correctly sum 2 JavaScript promise's results and return the result in a promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

I have an implementation that is incorrectly summing the 2 JavaScript promises and adding extra. It is expected that I would be able to return 3, but is returning 4. Is there something that I am missing?

```js
const timeToCountMs = 100;

const countingStartTime = Date.now();

const count = () => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, timeToCountMs));

async function getFirstCount() {
  await count();

  return Math.round((Date.now() - countingStartTime) / 50);
}

async function getSecondCount() {
  await count();

  return Math.round((Date.now() - countingStartTime) / 100);
}

async function getTotalCount() {

  var firstCount = await getFirstCount();

  var secondCount = await getSecondCount();

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(firstCount + secondCount);
  });
}

getTotalCount(); // results in 4, instead of 3
```

Comment: You're not calling `getSecondCount()` until after awaiting `getFirstCount()`, which means the second timer doesn't start until after the first one completes, so ~200ms has passed before the arithmetic in getSecondCount is evaluated. You should call both `getFirstCount()` and `getSecondCount()` before awaiting either of them. E.G. `const [ firstCount, secondCount ] = await Promise.all( [ getFirstCount( ), getSecondCount( ) ] );`, or `const firstPromise = getFirstCount( ); const secondPromise = getSecondCount( ); const firstCount = await firstPromise( ); const secondCount = await secondPromise;`

Comment: In a nutshell, 
(1) 100 / 50 = 2;
(2) (100 + 100) / 100 = 2;
(3) 2 + 2 = 4;

Answer (score 3):

`getFirstCount` returns `Math.round((Date.now() - countingStartTime) / 50)`, starts *immediately*, and resolves after 100ms, so the result is 2.

`getSecondCount` returns `Math.round((Date.now() - countingStartTime) / 100)`, starts *once getFirstCount* resolves (so, after 100ms), and resolves after another 100ms, so it's equivalent to:

```
Math.round((Date.now() - countingStartTime) / 100)
Math.round((200 ) / 100)
Math.round(2)
2
```

Check `countingStartTime` when each of the functions *start* running instead, rather than at the beginning of pageload. (That way, the difference between `Date.now` and `countingStartTime` will actually be the total running time of the function)

Also, avoid the explicit Promise construction antipattern - if you're in an `async` function, a Promise will already be returned by default, there's no need to construct a `new Promise` on top of that:

```js
const timeToCountMs = 100;
const count = () => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, timeToCountMs));
async function getFirstCount() {
  const countingStartTime = Date.now();
  await count();
  return Math.round((Date.now() - countingStartTime) / 50);
}

async function getSecondCount() {
  const countingStartTime = Date.now();
  await count();
  return Math.round((Date.now() - countingStartTime) / 100);
}

async function getTotalCount() {
  var firstCount = await getFirstCount();
  var secondCount = await getSecondCount();
  return firstCount + secondCount;
}

getTotalCount().then(console.log);
```